# '@' python decorator used to do something similar to method overriding in java?

Tags: java, python, flask, decorator

I am relatively new to python and have just recently been exposed to the '@' python decorator. I know it has many uses but I would like to clarify if my understanding of one of its uses more specifically its use in the following code, is correct.

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = connect_db()
```

I came across the decorator while working with Flask and am wondering whether the above code in python uses the '@' decorator to 'override' the method 'before_request' in the 'app' class. I don't know if python has any other form of method overriding like java but since I know java it would be easier for me to understand it this way if it is indeed the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python functions are first class objects, so that they may be passed as parameters.

I'll rewrite your function for the clarity of the following explanation:

```
@app.before_request
def f():
    g.db = connect_db()
```

First, `app.before_request` is function.

What happens here is the following:

```
def f():
    g.db = connect_db()

f = app.before_request(f)
```

So, function `app.before_request` is applied to function `f`.

As `app.before_request` is used as decorator, the result of `app.before_request` is assigned again to `f`. But in this case it doesn't matter. What is imporatant is that `app.before_request` makes something internally with `f` to make use of it.

Decorator is used just for concise and beautiful way of describing it.

You can achieve the same by this code (which I think is less readable than the one with decorator):

```
def f():
    g.db = connect_db()

app.before_request(f)
```

Comment: ok this makes way more sense than the docs I was reading. Thanks.

Comment: Decorators are a bit difficult at first to understand. But when you try working with them a bit, you will start getting them as quite simple thing. Just remember that functions in Python may be passed like any other object and that decorator just makes the only thing `f = decorator(f)`: applies and reassignes in one statement.